# How to get a URL parameter in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-parameters, query-string

I am facing an issue on getting the value of `tagid` from my URL: `localhost:8888/p?tagid=1234`.

Help me out to correct my controller code. I am not able to get the `tagid` value.

My code is as follows:

`app.js`:

```
var express = require('express'),
  http = require('http'),
  path = require('path');
var app = express();
var controller = require('./controller')({
  app: app
});

// all environments
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8888);
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.use(app.router);
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
  });
});
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

`Controller/index.js`:

```
function controller(params) {
  var app = params.app;
  //var query_string = request.query.query_string;

  app.get('/p?tagId=/', function(request, response) {
    // userId is a parameter in the url request
    response.writeHead(200); // return 200 HTTP OK status
    response.end('You are looking for tagId' + request.route.query.tagId);
  });
}

module.exports = controller;
```

`routes/index.js`:

```
require('./controllers');
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Express'
  });
};
```

Comment: In express, `/p?tagid=1234`, tagid is called a **query string**, not a URL parameter. A URL parameter would be `/p/:tagId`.

Answer (score 1040, accepted):

**Express 4.x**

To get a URL parameter's value, use [req.params](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params)

```
app.get('/p/:tagId', function(req, res) {
  res.send("tagId is set to " + req.params.tagId);
});

// GET /p/5
// tagId is set to 5
```

If you want to get a query parameter `?tagId=5`, then use [req.query](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query)

```
app.get('/p', function(req, res) {
  res.send("tagId is set to " + req.query.tagId);
});

// GET /p?tagId=5
// tagId is set to 5
```

---

**Express 3.x**

URL parameter

```
app.get('/p/:tagId', function(req, res) {
  res.send("tagId is set to " + req.param("tagId"));
});

// GET /p/5
// tagId is set to 5
```

Query parameter

```
app.get('/p', function(req, res) {
  res.send("tagId is set to " + req.query("tagId"));
});

// GET /p?tagId=5
// tagId is set to 5
```

Comment: Which version of express are you using? I just tested this on `express-3.4.4` and it works fine.

Comment: Remember to use `/p/5` if you're using the top solution, or `/p?tagId=5` if you're using the bottom solution.

Comment: The top solution(/p/5) works perfect for me..but bottom one /p?tagId=5 gives me error "tagId is set to undefined"

Comment: @user2834795, I'm not sure why you're having difficulty with `req.param`, I've added a `req.query` solution for you as well.

Comment: Thanks alot macek.you save my time.It was my mistake, i did all according to you but in url i was using "tagid" rather than "tagId".

Comment: `req.param()` is [deprecated](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param): `Use either req.params, req.body or req.query, as applicable.` For named route "parameters" (e.g. `/p/:tagId`) use [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params). For query strings (e.g. `/p?tagId=5`) use [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query).

Comment: What about /myurl/:guid/blahblha/sdfsd

Comment: I think that would be `app.get('/myurl/:guid/blahblha/sdfsd', function(req, res) { req.params.guid... })` – haven't used express in some time

Comment: req.query("someparam") gives me an error "req.query is not a function". What works for me is req.query.someparam. I'm using express 4.16.3. I realize this is almost a 5-year old question and just as old an  answer.

Answer (score 24):

You can do something like `req.param('tagId')`

Comment: This method has been deprecated. Use req.query instead.

Comment: @alextc `req.query` and `req.params` is so different things, the replacement for `req.param('x')` is `req.params.x` not req.query.

Answer (score 23):

**If you want to grab the query parameter value in the URL, follow below code pieces**

```
//url.localhost:8888/p?tagid=1234
req.query.tagid
OR
req.param.tagid
```

**If you want to grab the URL parameter using Express param function**

Express param function to grab a specific parameter. This is considered middleware and will run before the route is called.

This can be used for validations  or grabbing important information about item.

An example for this would be:

```
// parameter middleware that will run before the next routes
app.param('tagid', function(req, res, next, tagid) {

// check if the tagid exists
// do some validations
// add something to the tagid
var modified = tagid+ '123';

// save name to the request
req.tagid= modified;

next();
});

// http://localhost:8080/api/tags/98
app.get('/api/tags/:tagid', function(req, res) {
// the tagid was found and is available in req.tagid
res.send('New tag id ' + req.tagid+ '!');
});
```

Comment: best answer. tested ok

Answer (score 19):

This will work if your route looks like this: `localhost:8888/p?tagid=1234`

```
var tagId = req.query.tagid;
console.log(tagId); // outputs: 1234
console.log(req.query.tagid); // outputs: 1234
```

Otherwise use the following code if your route looks like this: `localhost:8888/p/1234`

```
var tagId = req.params.tagid;
console.log(tagId); // outputs: 1234
console.log(req.params.tagid); // outputs: 1234
```

Comment: generally  people do not make url like this `/p/:tagid=1234`