# Display dynamic webpage content based on URL parameter (Parse Cloud, Express, ejs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express, parse-platform

I'm new to programming and for this project I'm building a web app using Parse.com Cloud Code and Express. The structure looks like this:

- app.js (Express related codes)
- views/hello.ejs (template)
- main.js (cloud functions)

I also have an iOS app that can post a link on Facebook that looks like this: `myapp.parseapp.com/hello?objectid`. When Facebook users click that link and get redirected to the web app, the web app will automatically `res.render` the template based on the provided `objectid`. The `objectid` is then used to get some data, which will be displayed on the page, from a Parse class using Parse.Query, but my obstacle is not about Parse.Query.

To check if `objectid` is successfully captured by the server, I tried the following codes to render the template and insert the `objectid` into the placeholder for the `text` variable, but the `put objectid here` is not changed to the provided `objectid` when page is loaded. Can anyone tell me what went wrong, or if I should do this in another approach?

`hello.ejs (template):`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Web App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.post('/hello', {oid: window.location.toString().split("?")[1]});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><%= text %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

`app.js (express):`

```
// Initialize Express in Cloud Code.
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Global app configuration section
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body

// Render view
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.render('hello', { text: 'put objectid here' });
});

app.post('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.render('hello', { text: req.body.oid });
});

app.listen();
```

Comment: I found the solution in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089582/how-to-get-url-parameter-in-express-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I came across this post: [how to get url parameter in express node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089582/how-to-get-url-parameter-in-express-node-js). Decided to give it a try and it was successful! Here's the solution.

URL is changed to: `myapp.parseapp.com/hello?id=objectid`

The `<script>` in `<head>` is no longer needed. The final codes look like this:

`hello.ejs (template):`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Web App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><%= text %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

`app.js (express):`

```
// Initialize Express in Cloud Code.
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Global app configuration section
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body

// Render view
app.get("/hello", function(req, res) {
  res.render('hello', { text: req.param("id") });
});

app.listen();
```

Cheers!