# Don't understand how to send a string with the param for get request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So the first part of the instruction said make a get request for a turtles route, and send a JS object of the turtles and their colors, which I did here:

```
app.get('/turtles', function(req, res) {

data = {
    Raphael: "Red",
    Leonardo: "Blue",
    Donatello: "Black",
    Michaelangelo: "Orange"
}

console.log(data);
});
```

But the second part says make a get request for a 'turtles/:id' route that will send a string with the param: "The turtle you want to see is ------------" I'm not sure what I have to do.

```
app.get('/turtles/:id', function(req, res) {

data = {
   Raphael: "Red",
   Leonardo: "Blue",
   Donatello: "Black",
   Michaelangelo: "Orange"
  }
```

What would I have to console log here? req.params.id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get url parameter in express node js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089582/how-to-get-url-parameter-in-express-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want it to output the color of the selected turtle. So you might make a request for `/turtles/Raphael`. At this point, you'll need to retrieve the color of that turtle, and then output that color. So you might do something like:

```
app.get('/turtles/:id', function(req, res){
    var turtle = req.params.id;

    data = {
        Raphael: "Red",
        Leonardo: "Blue",
        Donatello: "Black",
        Michaelangelo: "Orange"
    }

    console.log("The turtle you want to see is " + data[turtle]);
});
```

Comment: `data.turtle` won't work since *turtle* is not defined as a variable in the object. However, `data[turtle]` will work.