# What does this syntax in http request mean?

Tags: node.js, http-get

I need to understand what this line of code means

```
app.get("/users/:id", function(req, res){
         var data = userModel.find().where('username', req);
         res.send(data);
     });
```

The part that I don't understand is "/users/:id", specifically the :id part. What does this syntax of http request mean?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089582/how-to-get-url-parameter-in-express-node-js

Comment: This isn't so much a Node.js thing, as it is an Express thing (which is a Node framework). ":id" denotes a variable-path. You can retrieve the value of "id" from request, but I don't know Express very well, so wait for someone else to come along.

Comment: Per [RFC3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3), a `:` is a normal, legal character in a path component in an URL other than the first component. So it should do nothing special in the client. In the server, it can do anything at all, just like any other path component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have above, sending a GET request to `/users/42` will result in `42` being stored at `req.params.id`.

Essentially, `:id` tells express that whatever is in the request URI where `:id` is in the route declaration should be interpreted stored on the `req.params` object with a property name of `id`.

You would most likely want something more similar to this:

```
app.get("/users/:id", function(req, res){
    var data = userModel.find().where('id', req.params.id);
    res.send(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Express uses the : to denote a variable in a route.
For example /user/42 will render a request for user id - 42
            /user/7  will render a request for user id - 7
but can be represented as a consistent form /users/:id
where id is the variable, : represents that whatever is after it is a 
variable, like here we have :id - id being the variable.

for reference check this out: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html
```