# Send URL parameters in Node,Express JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, server

I have an endpoint https://www..com

When I make a curl call, I have the endpoint as https://www..com?param1=true

I want to do a similar call from Nodejs, I am not sure if param1 should be passed in headers, concatenated to the endpoint or passed in options. What is the right way to do so?

My Node JS looks like this to make calls to my Node Server amd my file looks as follows,

```
    app.post('/thisway', function(req, res){
    var ENDPOINT = req.body.endPoint 
//(this gets me till https://<url> part of the endpoint string)
        var urlToHit = ENDPOINT.concat("?param1=true")
    var headers = {
            'Authorization': xxxxx,
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'X-Spark-Service-Instance': xxxxx
        }


    var options= {
        url: urlToHit,
        headers: headers,
        json: {xxxxxx}

          }
       request(options, callback);
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Always post the error

Comment: anything related with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089582/how-to-get-url-parameter-in-express-node-js?rq=1

Comment: This gives me an internal server error with not much description. I am not sure with the way I set my URL parameter set to true.

Comment: Post the server logs. "due to some reason" is not helping at all.

Comment: so you want to make a post request to `/thisway?variable=true` ?

Comment: yes. I want to send that "variable" as url parameter. Can you please look at my edited version and suggest if I can pass url parameter as a part of options(like json body)?

Comment: `due to some reason` does not help. You should post the error logs here.

Answer (score 2):

When doing a post it is not necessary to add a query string parameter in the route post. Mostly used for `app.get`. You can add the details in the `JSON` string data that you are sending. You can then use the `req.body` or `req.query` to get the item. However you can do it this way:

```
 app.post('/thisway/:variable', function(req, res){
```

Then you retrieve the parameter using `req.param.variable`

[**Good EXAMPLE**](https://webapplog.com/url-parameters-and-routing-in-express-js/)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) But the problem I am facing is something else, I have updated the question to reflect my problem better. Apologies for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as you have shown in your example in urlToHit. You don't have to pass it in header or options.

```
var urlToHit = ENDPOINT.concat("?param1=true")
```

This should complete the request with the needed parameters. Since even when you are doing a curl call, this is the endpoint you hit, it should be the same endpoint here as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your angularjs make a post request to `/thisway?variable=true` rather than `/thisway` and in your router you can configure as following:

```
app.post('/thisway', function(req, res){
    var variable = req.query.variable;

    if (variable) {
    //do something
    } else {
    //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) But the problem I am facing is something else, I have updated the question to reflect my problem better. Apologies for the inconvenience