# Node, AngularJS, Get a variable with url

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

if i set ID product on server and, list of products I show on client by http.get in AngularJS.

and in list html i have:
     a href="/product/edit/{{product.id}}">edit

Then i click on link and i have adress

http://localhost:3000/product/edit/1498057091291
in node i have 
router.get('/edit/:id', function (req, res, next)

How can i download from AngularJS variable with url if i set it in node, and i do not use NgRoute in AngularJS?

Sorry for my english

Comment: What are you using in node , `express` ? Show the code you have till now to give more details

Comment: yes express in node, tell me only how can i get the veriable with url i dont useing ngRoute

Comment: Show your angular code

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a24651626ece2f39995ef08dd4543677

and node:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a7e4117b0e5b20f9e614c0a8ecfabac2

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089582/how-to-get-url-parameter-in-express-node-js

Comment: U mean :

res.send(req.params.id);
 in node to browser?? when i will enter /edit ??