# How to retrieve data from server of a selected item in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm trying to create a website and i need to retrieve the full data of a selected item preview.

For example: Amazon gives you all the products matching your search query, and then you can click on them to get to single product page.
I would like to do the same thing.

So far i have already written my search and dynamic load of items into my page:

1) I have a node.js server which responds to a get request with a JSON file containing a list of elements (in my case, doctors)

```
app.get('/doctors', function(req,res){
  var config = require('./doctor.json');
  config.forEach(function(dottore) {
    var tableName = dottore.name;
    console.log(tableName);
    });
  res.send(JSON.stringify(config));
})
```

2) I make the request from my client side javascript like this:

```
$.get( '/doctors', function(data) {
$("<div class='row' id='dottori' ></div>").appendTo(".team");    
console.log(typeof data)

JSON.parse(data).map(addElement);    
 });

function addElement(doctor){
  console.log("Adding doctor");
  id=doctor.id;
  console.log(id);
  $("#dottori").append('<div class="col-md-4 ml-auto mr- 
              auto"><a href="./personaleGenerico.html" class="card card- 
        profile card-plain"><div class="btn btn-primary card-header card-header-image image-camminiamo"><img class="img" src="../assets/img/faces/4.jpg"></div><div class="card-body "><h3 class="card-title">'+doctor.name+'</h3><h4>Dott. in '+doctor.job+'</h4></div></a></div>');

}
```

And it works fine.

What i need to do now is to click on the preview of my doctor and load the page `personaleGenerico.html`, which should contain the full informations about that doctor.

I don't know how to associate the data on my server (which is a JSON containing all the informations of all doctors) to the element i've clicked.

For example: if i click the first doctor called "John", i will move to the page `personaleGenerico.html` filled with the information of that specific doctor (that are all avaiable in my JSON file)

Comment: I think I understand your question, but not 100% sure. Is the "personaleGenerico.html" a generic page which you want to populate information with, based on which doctor was clicked on?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: There are a large number of methods to do this. Arguably the easiest is to add a route to your backend that lets you select a specific doctor by id. Then call your page like personaleGenerico.html?id=1. Use that id parameter, pass it to the new backend route via ajax, and use that data as you see fit. Explaining how to do all of that in an answer would take too much time. If you can narrow your question a bit that would help guide the answers.

Comment: Sorry if i left the question too "open". I'm a beginner in this field, could you suggest me how to improve my question to make it clearer and narrower? I actually don't know what i specifically need to solve my problem, that's why my question is a bit "wide" . By the way your solution is on point, i have an idea of how to solve this, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need another backend endpoint that executes a different config/DB query. For that you'll need to send the ID of the doctor from the front end via URL params. see: [How to get a URL parameter in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089582/how-to-get-a-url-parameter-in-express)

ie:

```
app.get('/doctors/:id', function(req, res){
  var config = require('./doctor.json');
  const selectedDoctor = config.filter(function(doctor) {
      var tableName = doctor.name;
      console.log(tableName);
      return doctor.name === req.params.id
    });
  res.send(JSON.stringify(selectedDoctor));
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved a lot of problems. Just a last question: how do i get the id of the selected doctor? I know how to get it when i click on an element but, is it correct to add it into my HTML and then take the value of the id in my <div>? I have not fully understand where i should "store" the id of the first request

Comment: There will be front end state and backend state. So on the frontend youll have an id which yes could be the html tag. So you'll need to have id: 'someid' in your config.js file for each element. Then when you fetch ALL your doctors you'll populate each doctor element on the page with their data AND and id (that could be stored in the html id tag), then in the onclick handler for that element make sure that you get that id and send it over as a request param. Sorry for the delay, was out to lunch. If t helped make sure to upvote and mark as answered for others!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is two main way.

### 1 - rendering on server

You can use some html generator like [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), and your server response with a full html page with all info.

### 2 - rendering on client

Use AJAX call for fetch json info and then put data in html elements.
There is a lot of frameworks for dynamically create html elements from data: [vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) , [angular](https://angular.io/),...
However you can do it also in vanilla javascript creating html element with data and inject these into the DOM.

From what you say i think you want the rendering on server, if you use expressjs see [this example](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

## EDIT

Edit based on the comment response.

Assume that your data item has an identifier.
You have to create a route on server like this:

```
app.get('/doctor/:id', function(req, res){
    const doctorId = req.params.id;
    const doctors = require('./doctor.json');
    // I assume doctors is an Array
    const doctor = doctors.find(item => {
        return item.id === doctorId;
    });
    // you can response directly in JSON not need stringify/parse
    res.json(doctor);
});
```

you have also handle the case where doctor not exists.
Then you can call this route for fetch data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i know how to "push" data from server into my HTML. The problem is that i don't know how to tell to my server which doctor my client wants to load! 
To make it clearer : i know how to populate my generic page with the data i need, but i don't know how to get the right data associated with the doctor that I selected in the previous page.
I hope it's clearer now