# NODE.JS Cannot get my data right, any input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, body-parser

I am new to Node (frameworks in general), and I have some problems that I cannot find answers to after searching for days.

When I click on a specific client, I now get redirected to 'create-survey' which is correct. But after that I want the url to be something like '/create-survey/companyx' and get the data with me from that specific client that I clicked on in the new view '/create-survey/companyx'.

index.js:

```
 router.get('/create-survey/:company', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
Client.find({}, {}, function (err, docs){
    res.render('create-survey/:company', {"client" : docs});
})
});
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;

// Routes

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// Init App
var app = express();

// View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout:'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));


// Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

// Connect to Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use(express.static('public'));


// Set Port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Server started on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

and the last, create-survey.handlebars

```
<h2 class="page-header">Create a survey for {{client.company}}</h2>


<tr>
<strong>Company</strong>
<td><p>{{client.company}}</p></td>
<strong>Contact person</strong>
<td><p>{{client.contact}}</p></td>
<strong>Email adress</strong>
<td><p>{{client.email}}</p></td>



</div>
```

As I said, I'm a beginner that still is trying to learn, so come with all kind of feedback and help and I'll be happy!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a URL parameter in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089582/how-to-get-a-url-parameter-in-express)