# How to create function with parameter can pass express.get() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

**app** variable is defined by

```
const app = express();
```

This code is working fine:

```
app.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.json( post_creator.CreatePost(req.params.id) );
});
```

But the below code is not working:

```
const post_url_with_id = '/posts/:id';
app.get(post_url_with_id, (req, res) => {
    res.json( post_creator.CreatePost(req.params.id) );
});
```

How can i create function with parameter can pass express.get or post methods?

I want to implement like next function

```
function serve_post( post_url_with_id ) {
    app.get(post_url_with_id, (req, res) => {
        res.json( post_creator.CreatePost(req.params.id) );
    });
}
```

Thanks for contributors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a URL parameter in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089582/how-to-get-a-url-parameter-in-express)

Comment: No, it is different question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented by passing express `app` like:

```
// someRoute.js
function serve_post(app, post_url_with_id ) {
    app.get(post_url_with_id, (req, res) => {
        res.json( post_creator.CreatePost(req.params.id) );
    });
}

module.exports = serve_post;
```

In your file where you've instantiated `express` (where you have `app`)

```
const app = express();
// assuming they are in same folder
const someRoute = require('./someRoute');

someRoute(app, post_url_with_id);
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks.