# How do I insert a value into a select statement using JavaScript, specifically when using express and postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

How do I insert a value into a select statement using JavaScript, specifically when using express and postgres?

The createUser, and listAllUsers, is working (included below for reference). The try/catch is working and satisfying the request or throwing the error for those two as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

When using Postman, the output that I receive when I send the get (localhost:4000/user/id   with a x-www-formurlencoded key value user_id = 3) is…

```
{
    "name": "error",
    "length": 90,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42601",
    "position": "37",
    "file": "scan.l",
    "line": "1134",
    "routine": "scanner_yyerror"
}
```

And in the terminal, it shows the following (trapped from my console.log).

```
3
QUERY:  SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ${user_id}
```

When I user curl it says the same in the terminal. Here is the curl command and putput…

```
curl -X GET localhost:4000/user/3
```

{"name":"error","length":90,"severity":"ERROR","code":"42601","position":"37","file":"scan.l","line":"1134","routine":"scanner_yyerror"}ww10sc2353621:~ james.mcgreggor$ curl -X GET localhost:4000/user/3

Ultimately the 3 that I am passing as the user_id is not being substituted in the select statement. That is my problem. I cannot figure out how to correctly do this. Should I even be taking this approach, or should I try passing it as a parameter in the URL?

## This is from my User class file (User.js)

```
const db = require('../connectors/db.js');
class User {

  constructor(id, user_id, first_name, middle_initial, last_name, email, type) {
    this.id = id;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.middle_initial = middle_initial;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.email = email;
    this.type = type;
    this.user_id = user_id;
  }

  static newUser(user_id, first_name, middle_initial, last_name, email, type) {
     return db.one(`
      INSERT INTO users ("user_id", "first_name", "middle_initial", "last_name", "email", "type")
      VALUES ('${user_id}', '${first_name}', '${middle_initial}', '${last_name}', '${email}', '${type}')
  returning id
      `)
  }

  static async allUsers() {
    const findAllQuery = 'SELECT * FROM users;';
    return db.query(findAllQuery)
  }

  static async selectUser(user_id) {
    console.log(user_id);
    const findOneQuery = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ${user_id}';
    return db.query(findOneQuery)
  }
}

module.exports = User;
```

## This is from my Routes file (Routes.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const dataFunctions = require('./catalog.js');

const AppRouter = express.Router();

AppRouter.post('/user', dataFunctions.createUser);
AppRouter.get('/users', dataFunctions.listAllUsers);
AppRouter.get('/user/:id', dataFunctions.listUserByUserID);
AppRouter.delete('/user/:id', dataFunctions.deleteUserByUserID);

module.exports = AppRouter;
```

## This is from my Catalog file (Routes.js)

```
const Users = require('../models/users.js')

// Create

async function createUser(req, res) {
  try {
  console.log(req.body);
  const userId = await Users.newUser(req.body.user_id, req.body.first_name, req.body.middle_initial, req.body.last_name, req.body.email, req.body.type)
 res.status(201).send(`User ID: ${userId.id}`);
  } catch(error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
}

// List all

async function listAllUsers(req, res) {
  try {
  const userList = await Users.allUsers();
  console.log(userList);
  res.status(200).send(userList);
  } catch(error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
}

// List by ID

async function listUserByUserID(req, res) {
  try {
  const userList = await Users.selectUser(req.body.user_id);
  console.log(userList);
  res.status(200).send(userList);
  } catch(error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  createUser,
  listAllUsers,
  listUserByUserID
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using single quotes in select query in static async selectUser use ``.

Comment: Ah thank you for that, I was trying various options and overlooked the ``. The query still is not working. It may not be the query but my lack of how to handle URL queries/routes properly.

Comment: I have found a few things on how to handle queries and parameters in routes but can not seem to get it right.

Comment: I guess to start I should ask how do I correctly rewrite my route, so that I can get the url parameter? I have read through this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089582/how-to-get-a-url-parameter-in-express) but still have not had any luck

Comment: Hi JMcGreggor

Main problem with your route is 
`
AppRouter.get('/user/:id', dataFunctions.listUserByUserID);
`
your are making it a get request which passes the id in req.params not req.body.

follow the below
If route is a GET request like the below

`AppRouter.get('/user/:id',`
 
Access id with `req.params.id` 
If route is a post request like the below

`AppRouter.post('/user/:id',`

 access id with `req.body.id`

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much. That was very helpful. I have it partially working now. It does not seem like it matters what I put in after the : it still passes in the value. I have req.body.id working, but not req.params.id. I still am working through how all of it ties together which is why I want to get both working - so i have a better understanding. Thanks again for your help! I will post another comment with the final results once it is all working.

Comment: Please do not use this solution, it is vulnerable to SQL Injection, which is very easy to exploit.

Comment: Thanks ForbesLindesay. I agree, with you. This was just to get me started. Now I am working on sanitizing and protecting my queries. I will look at your example below.

Answer (score 1):

Never use string concatenation for querying, you already have mechanism called prepared statement, signature like

```
.query('SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author` = ?', ['David'])
```

It will sanitize input for you and partially prevent sql-injection attacks, also always do validation of input values. And if you are not want to use ORM like `typeorm`, `Sequelize`, you can use `knex.js` which can only create query strings and fully manage db interaction

Comment: Thanks for responding; I apologize for the late comment. I see what you are talking about with the risk of string concatenation. With my first try I just wanted to make sure that my basic query was working. Now I want to start cleaning it up and adding some security measures like you suggested. Once I feel comfortable with that, then I will probably try out Sequelize or typeorm, but i want to get the concepts down first before I rely a tool to show me. I will check out knex.js too! Thanks.

Comment: I did run into an issue with getting query to work though. For the life of me I could not get the id value to pass into the statement. I tried several variations but nothing seemed to make a difference. Do you have any idea what I may have been doing wrong? I will past my examples in the comment below.

Comment: `return db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', id);`

Comment: `return db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id]);`

Comment: `return db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', ['id']);`

Comment: `return db.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?', [id]);`

Comment: `var dbresult = db.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?', [id]);`

Comment: `var dbresult = db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id]);`

Comment: `var dbresult = db.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?`, [id]);`

Comment: Also, if you know of a better way to post the code snippets as comments please feel free to let me know ;)

Comment: Either way, the end result was that the id value was never passed into the ?. In the console I always saw the following... `     
QUERY:  SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?    `

Comment: FYI: I am checking that the id value exists in the function scope just before the query:     `    console.log(id);`

Answer (score 0):

You should never insert the values directly into your query like that. Consider the example:

```
db.query(`
  INSERT INTO messages (message, username)
  VALUES ('${message}', '${username}')
`);
```

If the `username` was my authenticated username, but the `message` was whatever value I typed into the UI, I could pretend to be someone else by sending a message like: `I am stupid', 'someone_else') --`

The SQL would then look like:

```
INSERT INTO messages (message, username)
VALUES ('I am stupid', 'someone_else') --', 'my_username')
```

The `--', 'my_username')` bit is treated as a comment, so it looks like `someone_else` said `I am stupid`. This is one of the most common and easily exploitable vulnerabilities in web applications.

### Solution 1

You could parameterise your query:

```
db.query(`
  INSERT INTO messages (message, username)
  VALUES (?, ?)
`, [message, username]);
```

This is secure, but harder to read (in my opinion) and you have to be very careful to always do this consistently.

### Solution 2

https://www.atdatabases.org provides database APIs that are relatively easy to use, and totally safe from this kind of attack. You would just do:

```
import connect, {sql} from '@databases/pg';

const db = connect();

db.query(sql`
  INSERT INTO messages (message, username)
  VALUES (${message}, ${username})
`);
```

to safely execute the same query. The `sql` tag ensures the data is properly handled/escaped and `@databases/pg` automatically enforces that you always add the `sql` tag. N.B. there are then no quotes around the parameters.

Comment: thanks for your recommendations. I used this in my project and it worked well. I appreciate the guidance!

Comment: Thanks @JMcGreggor, could you up-vote my answer to indicate that you found it helpful?