# Devise Omniauth : POST data using href link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, devise, omniauth

I would like to create a link  that could POST data.
Actually, I have a front in vuejs and a backend in rails.
I already have my own authentication system with Devise gem.
And I would like a user (who is already logged in) to be able to connect to other omniauth services (github, google...).

The problem is that as soon as I go on the link /auth/github (for example) my backend tells me that I didn't send the user's authentication token because i don't know how to send it.

That's why I would like to send datas (here, the auth token) directly from the link

Thanks

Comment: Aren't you solving the wrong problem here, why not ask how to send the token in the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Eyeslandic pointed out, your title is misleading, you have an `OAuth` or `OAuth2` problem not a link problem.

If I can guess correctly you are getting a `Get` response (the token is in the link) and you want it to be a `post` response (the token in the request body) ... Are you using `passport.js` ? Must be a matter of configuration.

There is nothing wrong with receiving the token in the link, `OAuth` protocols are secure enough, whether it's a `Get` or a `Post` response.

If you want to read the token from the link, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20089634/12594730).

```
login.get('/p', function(req, res) {
    const token = req.query.theReturnedTokenNameInTheLink
    res.send("My token is " + token);
});
```

And the token is just a key that give you access to the host (github, google, facebook ...) Api, you should make another request to those API's, in order to get the user data, you could use a library like `passport.js` to simplify things, here is one of the tutorials, I found on how to [use `passport.js`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-how-to-handle-authentication-with-node-using-passport-js-4a56ed18e81e/)

Good luck.

Comment: No, I think I explained it wrong.
In fact I am already connected and I already have my token. What I want to do is to open a page, the one to authorize an omniauth application, by making a html GET (through the <a/> tag) on my backend so that it redirects me to this page. The problem is that my backend asks for the authentication token to redirect me to the omniauth authorization page.